# How to extract frames from video using webcodecs from chrome 86

Tags: html5-video, frame, blink, video-codecs, webcodecs

[WebCodecs](https://github.com/WICG/web-codecs/blob/master/explainer.md)  is released in Chrome 86. But there's no real code example on how to use it yet. Given a video url, how to extract video frames as ImageData using webcodecs?

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is the entire complex process of acquiring raw bitmap-like data (e.g. something you can dump on a canvas), from a formatted file or a stream of data chunks.

In case of files (including the case where your URL points to a complete file, such as an `.mp4` file), this is generally made of 2 steps:

1. Parsing the container file into individual chunks of encoded video and/or audio
2. Decoding these chunks of encoded video/audio

WebCodecs only facilitates step 2 of this process, i.e. what is called *decoding*. The reasoning behind this decision was that parsing the container is computationally trivial, so you can efficiently do this with the `File` APIs already, but you still need to implement parsing/processing the container yourself.

Luckily, plenty of libraries exist already, many of which ironically existed long before the emergence of the WebCodecs API.

---

[MP4Box](https://github.com/gpac/mp4box.js/) is one example, helping you acquire encoded video and audio chunks, which you can then feed into a VideoDecoder or AudioDecoder.

With MP4Box, the key piece of your code will be centered around the `onSamples` callback you provide, and it'll look something like this:

```
        mp4BoxFile.onSamples = (trackId, user, chunks) =>
        {
            for (let i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++)
            {
                let chunk = chunks[i];
                let encodedChunk = new EncodedVideoChunk({
                    // you'll need to deep-inspect chunk to figure these out
                    type: "key", // or "delta"
                    timestamp: ...
                    duration: ...
                    data: chunk.data
                });

                // pass encodedChunk to a VideoDecoder instance's decode method
            }
        };
```

This is just a rough sketch of how your code will probably look, it probably won't work without more inspection, and it'll take a *lot* of trial and error, because this is very low level stuff.

WebCodecs is not the silver bullet you probably expected, but it can help you build one.